# Convergence to zero

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that if $n \rightarrow \infty$ then this sum converges to zero.

$$
 \sum_{k = [\frac{n}{2}]}^n
 {n \choose k}
 Q^k
 \cdot
 \left(
  1-Q
 \right)^{n-k}
$$

In this case $Q$ is constant and equals $e^{-1}$. But it seems that if this is true then it can be generalized for $Q < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: what are $C_n$?

Comment: @Crostul Presumably, $C_n^k=\binom{n}{k}.$

Comment: Yes, sorry for Russian notation =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you write is the probability of $P(\sum_{k=1}^nX_n \geq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor)$, where $X_i$'s are i.i.d Bernoulli variable with parameter $Q$.

$P(\sum_{k=1}^nX_n \geq \lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor) = P(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^nX_n -nQ}{\sqrt{n}} \geq \dfrac{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -nQ}{\sqrt{n}})$ and

\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -nQ}{\sqrt{n}} = \begin{cases} +\infty & Q < \frac{1}{2}\\ 0 & Q = \frac{1}{2} \\ -\infty & Q > \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}
\end{align}

So by [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), your sum converges to $P( G \geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -nQ}{\sqrt{n}})$, where $G$ is a centred normal distribution with variance $Q(1-Q)$. In particular we have

\begin{align}
P( G \geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor -nQ}{\sqrt{n}}) = \begin{cases} 0 & Q < \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{1}{2} & Q = \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 & Q > \frac{1}{2}\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, that's cool. I was thinking about this, but wasn't sure. Thanks =).